# Regular Expression Allowing Input For Only Numbers and One Decimal

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want an input text box that restricts users to only enter numbers and one decimal point.

The regular expression I am using currently is `/[^\d.]/g`.

Currently this allows the user to only input numbers and decimals but also allows for more than one decimal number. I am using it for a text box to allow only a string of numbers along with one decimal following another string of numbers but ends.

> Text box code: `onkeyup= "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' )"`.
> Full html block: `Enter your second number <input type="text" id="num2" onClick="(this.value='')" onkeyup= "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' )" />`

I have this expression here that highlights what I'm looking for `/^\d+(\.\d+)?/gm` it's just I need it completely in-versed.

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?/gm
/\d+(\.\d+)/gm 
/(^\d+[.]\d+)+[\d]+/gm
```

The preceding expressions allow input for everything but numbers and decimals. I need to allow only numbers and decimals for input.

I have seen others but none seem to accomplish exactly what I am looking for. I don't not want to allow negative numbers either but would like it optional.

- 12.00 - yes
- .124 - no
- -.07 - no
- -65 - no
- 124456 - yes
- 143467985.65534568746 - yes

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that input elements have a `pattern` attribute` for specifying allowed regex patterns, failing form validation if you try to submit. You don't need JS `on...` event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expression you are looking for is `/^\d+(\.)?\d+/gm`

You can view it with the test cases you provided on regex101, [here](https://regex101.com/r/wHXPrF/1)

> EDIT: As @Konrad Linkowski pointed out this does not work for single digits such as `1`. The updated regex `(^\.*)+(^0*)+^\d+(\.\d+)?` includes this edge case.

Comment: This doesn't work for single digits.

Comment: (^\.*)+(^0*)+^\d+(\.\d+)? I got it working with this in the tester. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Should work for any positive decimal number.